# Zend Framework Between Query

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

How can I write the following query in Zend Framework?

```
select * from hosted_plans where hp_id=15 and curdate() between discount_start_date and discount_end_date
```

In the query above the discount_start_date and discount_end_date columns are date fields in the table

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$query = $database->select ()
    ->from ('hosted_plans')
    ->where ('hp_id = ?', 15)
    ->where ('curdate() between discount_start_date and discount_end_date');
```

$database being a Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract descendant.

Answer (score 2):

One possible form with Zend 2:

```
    $select = $this->tableGateway->getSql()->select();
    $select->where(array('hp_id' => 15, new \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Expression('curdate() BETWEEN discount_start_date AND discount_end_date')));
    $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively:-

```
$query = $database->select ()
    ->from('hosted_plans')
    ->where('hp_id = ?', 15)
    ->where('curdate() >= discount_start_date')
    ->where('curdate() <= discount_end_date');
```

Would also work.